# How can I change Joomla admin URL

Tags: joomla

By default Joomla admin URL is yoursitename/administrator. How can I change this for Joomla 1.5 so that it doesn't affect my modules and components or any other thing on the backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that would be a good idea, because some links to '/administator' in modules/components are hardcoded (static), so you better should use some of these plugins http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection or just try something with .htaccess (ask for password, IP filtering etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Install the jSecure Authentication plugin.

Every Joomla back-end has the same URL. If you install a security plugin, you can add a suffix to your back-end URL to make it look like this: http://www.yoursite.com/administrator?helloworld

If the URL is not entered with a correct suffix, the site will redirect to a 404 (not found) page. Change the suffix regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I use the changeadmin component to kind of hide the admin url:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/14666

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Simple Step(And it's not a correct method but it works for me),

- Just Create a new folder in your root directory.
- create index.php (or some other name) in that folder, and add the following code

  ```
  $admin_cookie_code="2145446497812";
  setcookie("JoomlaAdminSession",$admin_cookie_code,0,"/");
  header("Location: ../administrator/index.php");
  ```
- Then add the following code inside administrator/index.php . Please make sure to add this immediately after opening the PHP tag.

  ```
  if($_COOKIE['JoomlaAdminSession']!= "159753987456321")
  {
      header('Location:../index.php');
  }
  ```
- Then try to access the administrator login by typing your root_joomla_address/new_folder_name. Then it will automatically redirect to your admin page. If you tried to access the default admin login page directly then it will redirect to the Joomla home page.

Hope this will works. I don't claim this a correct procedure. But if you looking to avoid a plugin, then this hack will help you.

Comment: Hacking administrator/index.php is a very bad idea and it would be overwritten the first time you update Joomla.

Comment: @BrentFriar , I know it's not the correct way.. But here am proposed this as simple one. Since am using stable version Joomla and the client don't want to update it and this hack works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with simple step you can restrict to access your administrator login page

Follow bellow steps:

before going through all steps first find your id address from this link [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com)

1. Create a .htaccess file in administrator folder.
2. Now write following code in .htaccess file

   ```
   <Limit GET POST> deny,allow deny from all allow from 192.168.0.1</Limit>
   ```

   3.Now write your own ip instead of 192.168.0.1
   4.Finally save the file and try to access your administrator page from your ip and different ip.

Hope it'll help. Thanks.

Comment: This is a tricky solution, but in case of IP change (e.g. using mobile data instead of DSL) this won't be useful.