# How can I change the Joomla administrator URL By PHP - No plugins

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla3.0

Since I'm new to Joomla I would like to know whether there is a way to change the administrator URL by **using PHP** rather than using a plugin or extensions. As far as I see using a 3rd party component is risky. I really don't want to use 3rd party extensions at all in mysite. How can I get it done?

By default Joomla administrator URL is yoursitename/administrator.

**changing constants** in /includes/defines.php and /administrator/includes/defines.php **does not work**.

Thanks

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751525/how-can-i-change-joomla-admin-url)

Comment: @Maxime Morin here Dasun is asking for a solution without plugins..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

referring [this post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=432&t=611287) you have got two options one through cpanel and other to use .htaccess..

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, you can't change the administrator URL however someone did post something regarding it on Stackoverflow.

Open the following files:

```
/includes/defines.php  >> line 25
/administrator/includes/defines.php  >> line 21
```

Else the only way might be using an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create a new directory in your root directory (eg. "newadminurl")

Step 2. Create an index.php file in your "newadminurl " directory..

```
$admin_cookie_code="3429020892";
setcookie("JoomlaAdminSession",$admin_cookie_code,0,"/");
header("Location: /administrator/index.php");
?>
```

Step 3. Add this to .htaccess of your real Joomla administrator directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !JoomlaAdminSession=3429020892
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

Explanation:

Now, you need to open "http://yoursite.com/newadminurl/"  before you open your “administrator” path. Here we have created a cookie that expires at the end of the session and redirect to actual administration page. Your actual “administrator”path is inaccessible until you don’t open on your secret link .

I hope this is what you are looking for.